# Cypress.$('abc').text() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I am trying to find a text of element using Cypress.$
All is working well with cy object but the Cypress.$ yields undefined

//This works

```
cy.get('abc').eq(0).find('xyz').then(($elm)=>{
                cy.log("$elm="+$elm.text())
            })
```

//This yields "undefined"

```
var elmText = Cypress.$('abc').eq(0).find('xyz').text()
cy.log(elmText)
```

Can some one help why Cypress.$ does not works here ??

Comment: My first guess would be to check if the element is rendered on the browser before you use the `Cypress.$`.

Comment: Yes it was. since I can get the text using cypress invoke function. Problem was mixing async-sync code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess that you have some cypress commands that must be completed before querying the selector. As cypress commands are asynchronous, your UI state is not ready when jquery is executed.
Thus, you can make it executed synchronously with cypress commands as follows:

```js
cy.then(() => {
   var elmText = Cypress.$('abc').eq(0).find('xyz').text()
   cy.log(elmText)
})
```

Comment: @mikhaliBolotov I want to avoid the then clause since i want to return the value of text()

Comment: Using any of cypress commands force you to make deal with asynchronicity. 
You can return not a string type but a Chainable<string> from your function. Also, you may consider using cypress aliases.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhali, there were indeed some commands that altered my execution flow. So even though data exists in the page by Cypress.$ was not able to get me those. Have separated the async-sync block now

Answer (score 2):

@MikhailBolotov is correct, synchronous code like `Cypress.$` in the same block as commands runs first.

Try out out this simple visit and heading check.

```js
it('asynchronous commands', () => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')
    .then(() => console.log('After visit'))

  var elmText = Cypress.$('h1').text()
  cy.log(elmText)
  console.log('At end of test')
})
```

The order of console.logs is

1. At end of test
2. After visit

As well as @MikhailBolotov'a suggestion, you can use hooks like `beforeEach` to break up the block and achieve what you want.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')
    .then(() => console.log('After visit'))
})

it('asynchronous commands', () => {
  var elmText = Cypress.$('h1').text()
  cy.log(elmText)
  console.log('At end of test')
})
```

The order of console.logs is now correct

1. After visit
2. At end of test

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Your example helped understand @Mikhali's solution. Have separated my async-sync code